# Left/right padding for Button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()?

Tags: android

I'm trying to set a left icon on a button with:

```
setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.foo, 0, 0, 0);
```

but the icon is placed flush up against the left edge of my button, and the text string. Is there a way to specify some left/right padding on the supplied icon so that it isn't right up against the edges?

Thanks

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is [`android:drawablePadding`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3adrawablePadding)

Here's an example of using `drawablePadding` along with `paddingLeft` and `paddingRight` to position an image in a button

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:drawablePadding="2dip"
    android:paddingLeft="30dip"
    android:paddingRight="26dip"
    android:text="Test" />
```

[image: Image example]

Comment: Nice, I didn't know this existed. Too bad it looks like there's no way to set the padding on only one side.

Comment: I added an example of putting padding on one side :)

Comment: That works, but what if you wanted extra padding just along the right edge of the image?

Comment: Just remove the paddingLeft attribute.

Comment: The padding along the right of the image isn't actually changed. Try using a longer string and you'll see it.

Comment: How do you do it in code, and also minimize the space between the image and the text?

Comment: @androiddeveloper, old question but maybe this will help someone else: yourTextView.setCompoundDrawablePadding(padding);

Comment: @JaredRummler I don't remember this question, but thanks. Any way to do it via XML ? Also, I think what you are suggesting is to add space, while I asked about reducing it to the minimal.

Answer (score 21):

For anyone looking for the programtic way, here is an example:

```
menuButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.foo, 0, 0, 0);
menuButton.setCompoundDrawablePadding(10);
```